# Deleting files on Server

Tags: server, files, removing

I have some files on my folder , something like : 1244 , 1244.backup ,1264 , 1264.backup , 1346 , 1346.backup ...And new pair automaticly downloads from server after pull new build. How i can delete all files without last 2 files with neewest download date/time ?

Comment: What does "last 2 files" mean? The last two in that list? The last two by creation date? The last two by modification date? Should we parse the file names for the date instead? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Thank you, corrected as you desired

Comment: What is "mew pair"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble "mew pair" should be "new pair"

Answer (score 1):

If you can be 100% sure your file names never contain spaces or other whitespace, you can do the simple, fragile and bad way:

```
ls -t | tail -n+3 | xargs rm
```

`-t` tells `ls` to sort by time, and `tail -n+3` means "start printing after the second line of input", so it will print all except the last two files. Finally, you pass these to `xargs rm` to delete them.

A better, safe and robust approach that would work for arbitrary file names is something like this:

```
stat --printf '%Y %n\0' * | sort -zrnk1,1 | cut -zd' ' -f 2- | tail -zn+3 | xargs -0 rm
```

The `stat --printf '%Y %n\0' *` will print the modification date (in seconds since the epoch) along with the file name for each file (or directory) in the current directory, ending each line with a NUL byte (`\0`) instead of a newline. This allows us to deal even with file names with newlines in their names.

Next, the `sort -zrnk1,1` sorts its NUL-terminated (`-z`) input, in reverse (`-r`) numerical (`-n`) order, according to the first field only (`-k1,1`). This is passed through `cut -zd' ' -f 2-` to remove the first space-separated field, which removes the timestamp. To illustrate:

```
$ ls -l *
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 11 15:00 'a bad file name'
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 11 15:00 'another'$'\n''bad file name'
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 12 15:00  file.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 12 15:00  file.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 12 15:00  file.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 12 15:00  file.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 12 15:00  file.5
```

Now, running the commands above gives:

```
$ stat --printf '%Y %n\0' * 
1665489608 a bad file name1665489610 another
bad file name1665576030 file.11665576031 file.21665576032 file.31665576033 file.41665576034 file.5

$ stat --printf '%Y %n\0' * | sort -zrnk1,1
1665576034 file.51665576033 file.41665576032 file.31665576031 file.21665576030 file.11665489610 another
bad file name1665489608 a bad file name

$ stat --printf '%Y %n\0' * | sort -zrnk1,1 | cut -zd' ' -f 2-
file.5file.4file.3file.2file.1another
bad file namea bad file name
```

All of this is finally passed to `tail -zn+3 | xargs -0 rm`  to delete the files as in the first example.